# useState default value problems since it's always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I learn React and JavaScript and have this React problem to understand `useStae`

I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wu-xi9n7?file=/src/MUITable.jsx:1139-1143).

I try to add default value to the 'useState´ like this:
(it's an array of `File`)

```
const [data, setData] = useState([ File ]);
```

And the File is this simple:

```
const File = (file) => {
    // do stuff
    return (
        <Return something with props file />
    );
};
```

What happens is that `data` is always undefined. I also tried like `useState([ {File} ]);`

Please advice?

[image]

Comment: Is it undefined when you run it?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the file? Is that a component you try to store in the state?

Comment: I think the File is a function that just returns an object (as can be seen in the comment) but you don't call it.

Comment: 'File' might be undefined at first.

Comment: I only want to call `setData` when all `File's`have been inserted since they have asynchronous stuff, I must also create code that ask the `data` `Files's` if they are done with the asynchronous

Comment: @BernhardJosephus as you see the image show undefined

Comment: is 'setNewFiles" a function ? useEffect will run if the values passed to the dependecy array changes. In your code, if setNewFiles is a function it will be triggered once, can you show us where is defined 'File' and 'setNewFiles' ?

Comment: I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wu-xi9n7?file=/src/MUITable.jsx:1139-1143).